# I can not figure out the proper BIOS configuration for these RAMs & this motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, troubleshooting

Long story short: aftr a bios reset I am unable to figure how to configure the bios so that it gets to POST. All I have now is beeps ( ---. = long long long short) repeating ad libitum. I looked it up on the manual and it is a generic RAM Error.

I tried changing frequency to 1333 and voltage to the lowest one, but nothing happens...

## **Noteworthy Components**

- Motherboard: `GA-990XA-UD3 rev 1`
- CPU: `AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Black Edition`
- RAM

  - 2x `Corsair XMS3 (Model: CMX8GX3M4A1600C9 Timings: 9-9-9-24 Voltage: 1.65)`
  - 2x `Kingston KVR (Model: KVR1333D3S8N9/2G Voltage:1.5 Timings: not reported on stick)`
- Graphics Card: `ASUS EAH5450 Series`

*Note: Before this BIOS reset everything worked perfectly. All the components have been tested on another system and worked. So, no blame to the hardware.*

## What works

I've been able to boot with only one Corsair in DIMM_1

## The Quest

To find the correct BIOS settings. We know that they exist because it worked before.

*Here is a bunch of pictures of the BIOS pages that I think have options that could solve the problem.*

## The BIOS Options

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

## Some Other Lore

I built this pc years ago and only opened some days ago to remove the consistent dust formations. Meanwhile I completely erased any memory of setting up that BIOS...

I think it is probably related with Ganged\Unganged, voltage, and frequency.

Comment: Was the machine off and unplugged when you cleaned the dust out of it?

Comment: Here is your memory support list, [might be some clues in the pdf](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Memory/memory_ga-990xa-ud3.pdf)

Comment: Normally default timings that are set after a bios reset will work, not sure what your problem is. May prove difficult for us to help you, sometimes these problems require hands on. Does each stick work on its own?

Comment: I Uploaded the pictures.

Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm writing from it. Everything was unplugged. My bad when I removed the bios battery to clean the seating...

I know for sure that a BIOS configuration that allows this system to boot exists. Maybe the order of operations is important, but I'm clueless here...

@Moab The modules I used are very similar models (the kingstons). the corsair have a different model beginning because of the fact that i got them in a kit. The kingstons alone don't POST if seated in slot 1.

Comment: Can you go to "Load Fail-Safe Defaults", and wipe out any and all other BIOS configuration that you've done, or is that an unavailable course of action (because you might have other customizations that you don't want to lose, and you don't want to figure out what they are and record those customizations?)

Comment: I already tried that multiple times, I also re-flashed the BIOS to the latest non-beta version (auto-loaading defaults in the process). Whenever I add a second stick I get beeps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the CPU with an AMD FX-8320E and setting the RAM clock at 1066. Now everything works fine.